# 'The formula you typed contains an error' in Excel Nested IF formula

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, excel-2007

I'm trying to create an excel formula for the below logic:

```
    If ((Value in A1 - 250000) >= 250000){
          Then Value in A2 = (0.05*(250000))
       }
    Else{
       If ((Value in A1 - 250000) <= 0){
           Then Value in A2 = 0
       Else{
           Value in A2 = (0.05*(Value in A1-250000))
       }
    }
```

Below is the formula I wrote:

```
    =IF(((A1-250000)>=250000), ((0.05*(250000))), IF (A1-250000)<=0, 0, (0.05*(A1-250000)))
```

And Excel throws following error

```
    The formula you typed contains an error
```

Any help with identifying the error is appreciated.

Comment: Your question and your formula don't seem to bear much resemblance to each other, but I think you want something like: `=MEDIAN(0,L10-250000,250000)*0.05`

Comment: Which version of Excel are you using? Are your tags deliberate? My answer only applies to later versions of Excel.

Comment: @Rory Sorry for the confusion. I have updated the question with correct formula.

Comment: @Bathsheba I'm using Excel 2007.

Comment: You only need to change L10 to A1 in the formula I suggested then. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this reproduces your logic:

```
=IF(A1>500000,0.05*250000,0.05*MAX(A1-250000,0))
```

or maybe even:

```
=0.05*MAX(0,MIN(A1-250000,250000))
```

although I agree that `IFS` might be more clear, but I think you need Office 365 for that function.

Comment: MIN, MAX formula worked for me. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

`IFS` is clearer:

```
=IFS(A1-250000 >= 250000, 0.05*250000, A1-250000 <= 0, 0, TRUE, 0.05*(A1-250000))
```

although if this is trying to compute something like a statistical measure, you could use an out of the box function like `MEDIAN`.

Reference: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/ifs-function-36329a26-37b2-467c-972b-4a39bd951d45

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This works fine with Office 365. Is there any other alternative for this in MS Office 2007?